# Is there a conceptual reason why every square complex matrix is similar to a complex-symmetric matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, soft-question

The question is maybe a bit vague, but like the title says: Every square complex-matrix $M$ is equal to $P S P^{-1}$ where $S = S^T$. The proof begins by taking the Jordan Normal Form of $M$, and then noting for each Jordan block $J$:

- If $J$ has dimensions $2n \times 2n$, then one can perform the similarity $J \to X^{-1} J X$ where $X = \begin{pmatrix} Q_n & -Q_n i \\ I_n & I_n i\end{pmatrix}$ and $Q_n$ is the matrix which is $0$ everywhere except on the antidiagonal, where it is $1$.
- If $J$ has dimensions $2n+1 \times 2n+1$, then one can perform the similarity $J \to X^{-1} J X$ where $X = \begin{pmatrix} Q_n & 0 & -Q_n i \\ 0 & \sqrt{2} & 0 \\ I_n & 0 & I_n i\end{pmatrix}$ and $Q_n$ is the matrix which is $0$ everywhere except on the antidiagonal, where it is $1$.

Other than that verification, I'm wondering if there's a more conceptual reason why it's true.

Comment: I can ask this question on MSE, if people prefer.

Comment: I don't claim this is a useful insight but the first thing that comes to mind for me is that there is an isomorphism from complex numbers $(a+bi)$ to a subset of the real $2\times2$ matrices $\begin{pmatrix} a & -b \\ b & a \end{pmatrix} $. I wonder if that fact might play a role here. We might ask are such matrices always similar to a 
"nice" real symmetric matrix as a starting point.

Answer (score 7):

Actually, there is one.

Let $k$ be any field. Note first that every square matrix is similar to a symmetric matrix if and only if every companion matrix is similar to a symmetric matrix (because every matrix is similar to a block diagonal matrix whose blocks are companion matrices).
This last property is equivalent to the following one: for any monic polynomial $f$ of degree $n\geq 1$, there exists a symmetric $n\times n$ matrix with minimal polynomial $f$.

Now we have the following lemma.

**Lemma.** Let $s:k[X]/(f)\to k$ be a linear functional such that the symmetric bilinear form $b_s: (x,y)\mapsto s(xy)$ has an orthonormal basis $\mathcal{B}$. Set $\alpha=X+(f)$, and let $\ell_\alpha$ be the left multiplication by $\alpha$ in the quotient ring. Then $S=\operatorname{Mat}(\ell_\alpha, \mathcal{B})$ is symmetric and has minimal polynomial $f$.

**Proof.** The fact that $\ell_\alpha$ has minimal polynomial $f$ is clear, is $\alpha=X+(f)$.
Now for all $x,y$, $s((\alpha x)y)=s(x(\alpha y))$ so $\ell_\alpha$ is self adjoint for $b_s$. But the matrix of a self adjoint endomorphism in a $b_s$-orthonormal basis is symmetric.

Now, at least if $k$ has characteristic not 2, it is easy to produce an example of $s$ such that $b_s$ is non degenerate (take for example $s(\alpha^i)=\delta_{i,0}$ for $i=0,\dotsc,n-1$).

But if $k=\mathbb{C}$, then any non degenerate symmetric bilinear form has an orthonormal basis, hence we are done.

But there is better. In fact, we have:

**Thm.** Let $k$ be a field of characteristic not 2. Assume that $-1$ is a square in $k$. Then every matrix with entries in $k$ is similar to a symmetric one.

**Proof.** By what we have done previously, it is enough, for a given $f$, to find an $s:k[X]/(f)\to k$ such that $b_s$ has an orthonormal basis.

Set $s(\alpha^i)=1$ for $i=0,\dotsc,n-1$ .

If $n=2m$, then $b_s$ is hyperbolic, since a Lagrangian is given by the linear span of $1,\alpha,\dotsc,\alpha^{m-1}$. Hence $b$ is isomorphic to $m$ copies of a hyperbolic plane $\langle 1,-1\rangle$ (this uses the fact that $2$ is invertible), which is isomorphic to $\langle 1,1\rangle$ since $-1$ is a square. Hence $b_s$ is isomorphic to the unit form, meaning that it has an orthonormal basis.

If $n=2m$, set $V=\operatorname{Span}(x^m)$. Then $b_s(x^m,x^m)=1$ and $k[X]/(f)=V\oplus V^\perp$. Now, the span of $1,\dotsc,x^{m-1}$ is a Lagragian of $V^\perp$,so  $V^\perp$ has an orthonormal basis as before. Now add $x^m$ to this basis to obtain an orthonormal basis of $k[X]/(f)$.

We can now characterize the fields $k$ for which every square matrix is similar to a symmetric one.

**Thm.** Let $k$ be a field with characteristic different from $2$. Then the following conditions are equivalent:

(i) For all $n\geq 1$, every $n\times n$ matrix with entries in $k$ is similar to a symmetric one

(ii) Every $2\times 2$ matrix with entries in $k$ is similar to a symmetric one

(iii)  $-1$ is a square in $k$.

**Proof.** (i) $\Rightarrow$ (ii): ok.

(ii) $\Rightarrow$ (iii). By previous considerations, (ii) implies that there is a $2\times 2$ symmetric matrix with minimal polynomial $X^2$.
Such matrix $S$ is nonzero and has the form $S=\pmatrix{\phantom{-}a & b\cr b & a}$ with $a^2+b^2=0$. Since $S$ is nonzero, $a$ or $b$ is nonzero, and $-1$ is a square.

(iii) $\Rightarrow$ (i): this is the previous theorem.

If $k$ has characteristic 2, then the answer is a bit different.

**Thm.** Assume $\operatorname{char}(k)=2$.

Then the following conditions are equivalent:

(i) For all $n\geq 1$, every $n\times n$ matrix with entries in $k$ is similar to a symmetric one

(ii) Every $2\times 2$ matrix with entries in $k$ is similar to a symmetric one

(iii)  Every element of $k$ is a square (that is, $k$ is perfect).

**Proof.** Assume that $S$ is a symmetric matrix of size $2$ with minimal polynomial $X^2-d$. Such a matrix $S$ is nonzero and has the form $S=\pmatrix{a & b\cr b & a}$ with $a^2+b^2=(a+b)^2=d$, so $d$ is a square.

So it remains to prove that if every element is a square, then every monic polynomial of degree $n$ is the minimal polynomial of an $n\times n$ matrix.

The criterion used above is still valid (we use bilinear forms, not quadratic forms). It is well known that a non alternating non degenerate symmetric bilinear form has an orthogonal basis. Since every element is a square, one can then deduce an orthonormal basis.

Hence, it is enough to produce a linear function $s:k[X]/(f)\to k$ such that $b_s$ is non alternating and non degenerate.

This is not too difficult, even if I don't remember the standard example right away.

Comment: Do you mean odd characteristic to include $0$?

Comment: You're right, it's badly phrased. I replaced "odd characteristic" by "characteristic not 2".

Comment: This is the perfect setting for the idea of the "characteristic exponent" of a field, which is $p$ if the field has characteristic $p > 0$ and $1$ if the field has characteristic $0$, so that "odd characteristic exponent" has exactly the meaning that one hopes. \\ What does "The fact that $\ell_\alpha$ has minimal polynomial $f$ is clear, is $\alpha=X+(f)$" mean?  Should "is" be "if"?